# What are the benefits of Cross Stage Partial Connections over Residual Connections?

Tags: deep-learning, residual-networks

Cross Stage Partial Connections (CSPC) try to solve the next problems:

1. Reduce the computations of the model in order to make it more suitable for edge devices.
2. Reduce memory usage.
3. Better backpropagate the gradient.

I cannot really understand how the first two points are actually achieved with this type of connection. Furthermore, in CSPC, the skip connection is just a slice of the feature map, and in Residual Connections, the skip connection is all the feature map. Aren't CSPC and Residual Connections (with concatenation) actually "almost" the same thing? Then, what advantages do you get for connecting with deeper layers only a slice of the previous feature map (CSPC) vs the whole feature map (Residual Connection)?